# Calling AWS RDS CreateDBSnapshotAsync Asynchronously "Set It And Forget It"

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, rds

In an AWS Lambda function, I would like to be able to call a component to create a RDS DB Snapshot.  There is an async method on the client named CreateDBSnapshotAsync.  But, because this is AWS Lambda, I only have 5 minutes to complete the task.  So, if I await it, the AWS Lambda function will timeout.  And, apparently when it times out, the call is cancelled and then the snapshot is not completed.

Is there some way I can make the call in a COMPLETELY asynchronously way so that once I invoke it, it will complete no matter if my Lambda function times out or not?
In other words, I don't care about the result, I just want to invoke the process and move on, a "set it and forget it" mentality.

My call (without the await, obviously) is as below

```
        using (var rdsClient = new AmazonRDSClient())
        {
            Task<CreateDBSnapshotResponse> response = rdsClient.CreateDBSnapshotAsync(new CreateDBSnapshotRequest($"MySnapShot", instanceId));
        }
```

As requested, here's the full method:

```
    public async Task<CloudFormationResponse> MigrateDatabase(CloudFormationRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        LambdaLogger.Log($"{nameof(MigrateDatabase)} invoked: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));


        if (request.RequestType != "Delete")
        {
            try
            {
                var migrations = this.Context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().OrderBy(b=>b).ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < migrations.Count(); i++)
                {
                    string thisMigration = migrations [i];
                    this.ApplyMigrationInternal(thisMigration);
                }
                this.TakeSnapshotAsync(context,migrations.Last());
                return await CloudFormationResponse.CompleteCloudFormationResponse(null, request, context);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LambdaLogger.Log(e.ToString());
                if (e.InnerException != null) LambdaLogger.Log(e.InnerException.ToString());
                return await CloudFormationResponse.CompleteCloudFormationResponse(e, request, context);
            }
        }
        return await CloudFormationResponse.CompleteCloudFormationResponse(null, request, context);

    }

    internal void TakeSnapshotAsync(ILambdaContext context, string migration)
    {

        var instanceId = this.GetEnvironmentVariable(nameof(DBInstance));

        using (var rdsClient = new AmazonRDSClient())
        {


            Task<CreateDBSnapshotResponse> response = rdsClient.CreateDBSnapshotAsync(new CreateDBSnapshotRequest($"{instanceId}{migration.Replace('_','-')}", instanceId));
            while (context.RemainingTime > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(15000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Underneath, it's a HTTP call.  My impression is that once the call is made, it would continue to process.  I believe in the timeout, the dispose of the AmazonRDSClient is calling cancel on the operation.

Comment: Then just remove the `using` block. calling an async call from within a `using block` will definitely cause the client to be disposed before its time.

Comment: Can you show the function encapsulating that call.

Comment: is `TakeSnapshotAsync` the actual AWS lambda function handler or a called sub-method within the function?

Comment: It's a method on the Amazon SDK:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RDS/MRDSCreateDBSnapshotAsyncCreateDBSnapshotRequestCancellationToken.html

Comment: No I am referring to your encapsulating `TakeSnapshotAsync`. I have already identified the `CreateDBSnapshotAsync` in the SDK

Comment: Show the entire Function class

Comment: I posted most of the class, the rest should be irrelevant.  It is called from MigrateDatabase after all the migrations have been applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First refactor that sub function to use proper async syntax along with the use of `Task.WhenAny`.

```
internal async Task TakeSnapshotAsync(ILambdaContext context, string migration) {
    var instanceId = this.GetEnvironmentVariable(nameof(DBInstance));
    //don't wrap in using block or it will be disposed before you are done with it.
    var rdsClient = new AmazonRDSClient();
    var request = new CreateDBSnapshotRequest($"{instanceId}{migration.Replace('_','-')}", instanceId);
    //don't await this long running task
    Task<CreateDBSnapshotResponse> response = rdsClient.CreateDBSnapshotAsync(request);
    Task delay = Task.Run(async () => {
        while (context.RemainingTime > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)) {
            await Task.Delay(15000); //Don't mix Thread.Sleep. use Task.Delay and await it.
        }
    }
    // The call returns as soon as the first operation completes, 
    // even if the others are still running.
    await Task.WhenAny(response, delay);
}
```

So if the `RemainingTime` runs out, it will break out of the call even if the snap shot task is still running so that the request does not time out.

Now you should be able to await the snapshot while there is still time available in the context

```
public async Task<CloudFormationResponse> MigrateDatabase(CloudFormationRequest request, ILambdaContext context) {
    LambdaLogger.Log($"{nameof(MigrateDatabase)} invoked: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));

    if (request.RequestType != "Delete") {
        try {
            var migrations = this.Context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().OrderBy(b=>b).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < migrations.Count(); i++) {
                string thisMigration = migrations [i];
                this.ApplyMigrationInternal(thisMigration);
            }
            await this.TakeSnapshotAsync(context, migrations.Last());
            return await CloudFormationResponse.CompleteCloudFormationResponse(null, request, context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LambdaLogger.Log(e.ToString());
            if (e.InnerException != null) LambdaLogger.Log(e.InnerException.ToString());
            return await CloudFormationResponse.CompleteCloudFormationResponse(e, request, context);
        }
    }
    return await CloudFormationResponse.CompleteCloudFormationResponse(null, request, context);

}
```

This should also allow for any exceptions thrown by the RDS client to be caught by the currently executing thread. Which should help with troubleshooting any exception messages.

Some interesting information from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html#dot-net-async).

> #### Using Async in C# Functions with AWS Lambda
>
> If you know your Lambda function will require a long-running process, such as uploading large files to Amazon S3 or reading a large stream of records from DynamoDB, you can take advantage of the async/await pattern. When you use this signature, Lambda executes the function synchronously and waits for the function to return a response or for execution to [time out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html).

From [docs about timeouts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html)

> ### Function Settings
>
> ...
>
> - **Timeout** – The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run before stopping it. The default is 3 seconds. The maximum allowed value is 900 seconds.

If getting a HTTP timeout then shorten the delay but leave the long running task. You still use the `Task.WhenAny` to give the long running task an opportunity to finish first even if that is not the expectation.

```
internal async Task TakeSnapshotAsync(ILambdaContext context, string migration) {
    var instanceId = this.GetEnvironmentVariable(nameof(DBInstance));
    //don't wrap in using block or it will be disposed before you are done with it.
    var rdsClient = new AmazonRDSClient();
    var request = new CreateDBSnapshotRequest($"{instanceId}{migration.Replace('_','-')}", instanceId);
    //don't await this long running task
    Task<CreateDBSnapshotResponse> response = rdsClient.CreateDBSnapshotAsync(request);
    Task delay = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));
    // The call returns as soon as the first operation completes, 
    // even if the others are still running.
    await Task.WhenAny(response, delay);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check it out (when us-east-1 RDS is back up).  I didn't know they upped the time limit from 5 to 15 minutes.

Comment: I suggest checking the link to see if there were any other changes you were not aware of.

Comment: Well, it did not work.  But, I'm not sure why and don't have time to dig completely down into it.  But your insight was definitely worth the bounty.

Comment: So, I had time to look @ this closer.  The root problem was the Lambda function did not have the rds:CreateDBSnapshot permission.  The issue was that calling it completely async without the await was causing the exception to not throw and therefore not caught or logged.  I just plain awaited the call and then the permission exception bubbled up.  Inevitably, the API is designed to handle this situation, it DOES just invoke and return in a relatively quick manner (1-2 seconds) and the snapshot creation continues on its merry way.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TimBassett great. Glad to know a solution was found. Happy coding.